# Estoy intentado programar un web scraper y no estoy obteniendo el Output que busco

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Intenté programar un web scraper para que buscara en una página de publicaciones científicas y me devolviera los títulos relacionados con un tema en específico. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
import pandas as pd
driver.get('https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=sports+nutrition')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

url='https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=sports+nutrition'
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")

#Pubmed titles for Sports Nutrition
SNTitles= soup.selectAll('a class', class_='docsum-title')

print (SNTitles)    
titles = list()
for i in SNTitles:
    titles.append(i.text)
    
print(titles)
```

Ese código me devuelve: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.
Busqué en internet y después de cambiarle varias cosas al código, me devuelve otros errores o en algún caso me devolvió:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Alguien tiene idea de que puedo modificar en mi codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Estás pasándole una URL a BeatufilSoup, pero este objecto acepta contenido. Quizás sólo necesites eliminar estas dos líneas para que funcione:

```py
url='https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=sports+nutrition'
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")
```

Deberías pasarle el contenido que te devuelve la URL usando un cliente HTTP, como haces previamente con Selenium.

```py
driver.get('https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=sports+nutrition')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```